# Make an image fits its parent element

Tags: jquery, css, image

I have an upright div (width = 33% of body; height = 100% of body) which contains an image. This image should cover the whole div **without** loosing its aspect ratio. I use height = 100% at the moment but that stretches the width beyond the parental div. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a background image instead, using the `cover` attribute for `background-size`, e.g.:

```
<div class="my-tall-div">
  <!-- no image tag needed any more -->
</div>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
.my-tall-div {
  background: url(/path/to/image.jpeg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I need to use the <img> since it's needed for a plugin.

Comment: You'll need to write some javascript then to resize and centre it. Why does it need to be an `<img>` tag for the plugin?

Comment: Just used another plugin, so your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it. Please accept my answer then :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is min-width:100%; or set the pixels of your website. Then it will also be responsive

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can still use @toomanyredirects answer.

Just tweak it so the class is set to the `<img>` tag.

```
.imgCover
{ 
  background: url(imgpath) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<img class="imgCover" ... >
```