# Fit image to its full width of screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit an image to its full width of the browser. Please let me know CSS code for that. I am using px for container. So let me know according to that. I don't want scroll bars to full screen of the browser. I am trying width:100%, width in px. But nothing works I see scroll bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an image fits its parent element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991641/make-an-image-fits-its-parent-element)

Answer (score 2):

Images have their own display type in CSS, so when you say something like `width:100%`, it fills to 100% of the original image's dimensions rather than acting like a block and expanding to fill 100% of the parent element.

You can fix that by changing the display type, though only for that one image:

```
<style type="text/css">
  img.big-img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
  }
</style>

…

<img src="my_image.jpg" class="big-img">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to depend on browser's viewport add this to your element's css and it will stretch automatically

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: Using position :absolute disturbs the whole website. So this is not working for me!